# bash - PUT data with curl with variables from file

Tags: json, bash, curl, theforeman

I have a bash script like this

```
#!/bin/bash

while read fqdn hostname; do
curl -H "Content-Type:application/json" -XPUT "https://server/api/hosts/${fqdn}" -d '{"host":{"name": "'${hostname}'"}}' --cacert bundle.pem --cert pnet-pem.cer --key privkey.pem
done <curl1.txt
```

The file curl1.txt contains of

fqdn   (tab)hostname

..........

I have to update some data using theForeman API. I have a lot fqdns and hostnames so I've wrote the script above. The problem is with JSON, because I get an error like this:

```
{"status":400,"error":"There was a problem in the JSON you submitted: 795: unexpected token at '{\"host\":{\"name\": \"ptesrv02-lub\r\"}}'"}
```

When I put `'{"host":{"name": "${hostname}"}}'` instead `'{"host":{"name": "'${hostname}'"}}'` I get

```
{
  "error": {"id":130,"errors":{"interfaces.name":["is invalid"],"name":["is invalid"]},"full_messages":["Name is invalid","Name is invalid"]}
}
```

So where is the problem? Can You help me with that?

Comment: You've a trailing `\r` character in your `${hostname}` value: `ptesrv02-lub\r` . This is very likely to be the issue.

Comment: Ok, so what means \r ? In text file I have no sign like this and the file is generated by ruby script.

Comment: @alaSmith: if the variable contains `\r` as @threadp suggests, do `hostname=$(echo $hostname|tr -d '\r')` before triggering the `curl` command

Comment: try  `${hostname%?}`

Comment: @alaSmith also check: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/29075/difference-between-n-and-r-n

Comment: salih, Inian thank You for help, both methods works :)

Comment: @Inian since you were the first one to present a working solution, please put your comment as an answer so OP can accept it.

Comment: @salih You should also provide your answer as it is an alternate and helpful method.

Comment: @alaSmith: You can click on the small tick-mark on the left of the answer below for accepting the post, thereby marking the post as solved.

Comment: In general, don't try to build dynamic JSON by hand; use a tool like `jq` to ensure that the contents of your variables are properly encoded.

Answer (score 1):

To remove trivial special characters from files copied from Windows(`CR-LF` endings) 'tr' command can be used as

```
hostname=$(echo $hostname|tr -d '\r')
```

in your example above. Presence of these special characters mangles how `bash` treats characters.

Credits to [`threadp`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5595825/threadp) for pointing out the presence of special characters in the `hostname` variable.

If you ever suspect the file to have such `CR-LF` endings, you can confirm by searching for them by using `grep`, treating the file as binary

```
grep -U $'\015' curl1.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

As [threadp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5595825/threadp) pointed, you have a trailing `\r` character. You can try this to remove it.

```
${hostname%?}
```

This usage just remove last character, in this scenario, it was trailing `\r`.
But, it is better to use

```
${hostname/$'\r'/}
```

Thanks [123](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4923629/123)

Comment: That will just remove the last character, better to use something like  `"${hostname/$'\r'/}"`